# Expose port from container in a pod minikube kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

I'm new to K8s, I'll try minikube with 2 container running in a pod with this command:

```
kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml
```

and this deployment.yml:

```html
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: site-home
spec:

  restartPolicy: Never

  volumes:
  - name: v-site-home
    emptyDir: {}

  containers:


  - name: site-web
    image: site-home:1.0.0
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80
    volumeMounts:
    - name: v-site-home
      mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html/assets/quotaLago
  
  - name: site-cron
    image: site-home-cron:1.0.0
    volumeMounts:
    - name: v-site-home
      mountPath: /app/quotaLago
```

I've a shared volume so if I understand I cannot use deployment but only pods (maybe stateful set?)

In any case I want to expose the port 80 from the container site-web in the pod site-home. 
In the official docs I see this for deployments:

```
kubectl expose deployment hello-node --type=LoadBalancer --port=8080
```

but I cannot use for example:

```
kubectl expose pod site-web --type=LoadBalancer --port=8080
```

any idea?

Comment: What error you get !! With `kubectl expose pod` command ?

Comment: Also your containers within a given Pod share an IP address and port space, and can find each other via localhost.

Comment: see my comment on mario's answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> but I cannot use for example:
>
> ```
> kubectl expose pod site-web --type=LoadBalancer --port=8080
> ```

Of course you can, however exposing a single `Pod` via `LoadBalancer` `Service` doesn't make much sense. If you have a `Deployment` which typically manages a set of `Pods` between which the real load can be balanced, `LoadBalancer` does its job. However you can still use it just for exposing a single `Pod`.

Note that your container exposes port `80`, not `8080` (`containerPort: 80` in your `container` specification) so you need to specify it as `target-port` in your `Service`. Your `kubectl expose` command may look like this:

```
kubectl expose pod site-web --type=LoadBalancer --port=8080 --target-port=80
```

If you provide only `--port=8080` flag to your `kubectl expose` command it assumes that the `target-port`'s value is the same as value of `--port`. You can easily check it by yourself looking at the service you've just created:

```
kubectl get svc site-web -o yaml
```

and you'll see something like this in `spec.ports` section:

```
- nodePort: 32576
    port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
```

After exposing your `Pod` (or `Deployment`) properly i.e. using:

```
kubectl expose pod site-web --type=LoadBalancer --port=8080 --target-port=80
```

you'll see something similar:

```
  - nodePort: 31181
    port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
```

After issuing `kubectl get services` you should see similar output:

```
NAME                            TYPE           CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP      PORT(S)          AGE
site-web                              ClusterIP      <Cluster IP>   <External IP>           8080:31188/TCP         4m42s
```

If then you go to `http://<External IP>:8080` in your browser or run `curl http://<External IP>:8080` you should see your website's frontend.

Keep in mind that this solution makes sense and will be fully functional in cloud environment which is able to provide you with a real load balancer. Note that if you declare such `Service` type in Minikube in fact it creates [NodePort](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport) service as it is unable to provide you with a real load balancer. So your application will be available on your Node's ( your Minikube VM's ) IP address on randomly selected port in range `30000-32767` (in my example it's port `31181`).

As to your question about the volume:

> I've a shared volume so if I understand I cannot use deployment but
> only pods (maybe stateful set?)

yes, if you want to use specifically [EmptyDir](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#emptydir) volume, it cannot be shared between different `Pods` (even if they were scheduled on the same node), it is shared only between containers within the same `Pod`. If you want to use `Deployment` you'll need to think about another storage solution such as [PersistentVolume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/).

---

### Edit

In the first moment I didn't notice the error in your command:

```
kubectl expose pod site-web --type=LoadBalancer --port=8080
```

You're trying to expose non-existing `Pod` as your `Pod`'s name is `site-home`, not `site-web`. `site-web` is a name of one of your containers (within your `site-home` `Pod`). Remember: we're exposing `Pod`, not `containers` via `Service`.

> I change 80->8080 but I always come to `error:kubectl expose pod site-home --type=LoadBalancer --port=8080 return:error: couldn't retrieve selectors via --selector flag or introspection: the pod has no labels and cannot be exposed` See `'kubectl expose -h'` for help
> and examples.

The key point here is: `the pod has no labels and cannot be exposed`

It looks like your `Pod` doesn't have any `labels` defined which are required so that the `Service` can select this particular `Pod` (or set of similar `Pods` which have the same label) from among other `Pods` in your cluster. You need at least one label in your `Pod` definition. Adding simple label `name: site-web` under `Pod`'s `metadata` section should help. It may look like this in your `Pod` definition:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: site-home
  labels:
    name: site-web
spec:
...
```

Now you may even provide this label as selector in your service however it should be handled automatically if you omit `--selector` flag:

```
kubectl expose pod site-home --type=LoadBalancer --port=8080 --target-port=80 --selector=name=site-web
```

**Remember:** in Minikube, a real load balancer cannot be created and instead of `LoadBalancer` `NodePort` type will be created. Command `kubectl get svc` will tell you on which port (in range `30000-32767`) your application will be available.

> and `kubectl expose pod site-web --type=LoadBalancer
> --port=8080 return: Error from server (NotFound): pods "site-web" not found. Site-home is the pod, site-web is the container with the port
> exposed, what's the issue?

If you don't have a `Pod` with name `"site-web"` you can expect such message. Here you are simply trying to expose non-existing `Pod`.

> If I exposed a port from a container the port is automatically exposed also for the pod ?

Yes, you have the port defined in Container definition. Your `Pods` automatically expose all ports that are exposed by the `Containers` within them.

Comment: I change 80->8080 but I always come to error:`kubectl expose pod site-home --type=LoadBalancer --port=8080`  return:`error: couldn't retrieve selectors via --selector flag or introspection: the pod has no labels and cannot be exposed  See 'kubectl expose -h' for help and examples` and `kubectl expose pod site-web --type=LoadBalancer --port=8080` return: `Error from server (NotFound): pods "site-web" not found` Site-home is the pod, site-web is the container with the port exposed, what's the issue?If I exposed a port from a container the port is automatically exposed also for the pod?

Comment: Please see the EDIT section of my answer.

Comment: `It looks like your Pod doesn't have any labels defined which are required so that the Service can select this particular Pod (or set of similar Pods which have the same label) from among other Pods in your cluster.` I've noticed this reliance on Labels-as-Selectors a lot in Kubernetes. What's the reasoning for it? I agree that selecting by Labels is _usually_ the correct (more extensible, etc.) choice - but why is select by name _forbidden_ rather than simply discouraged? (EDIT oh yuck, I always forget that SO forbids Newlines in comments. I've delimited the quote in monospacing instead)